# SpringBootでHTMLファイルをダウンロードしたい

Tags: java, spring-boot

SpringBootでHTMLファイルをダウンロードしたいです。
どのように考えていいのかがわからないのですが、
①テンプレートとなるHTMLを用意して、一部分を表示したい内容に変更
②変更したHTMLファイルをダウンロード

こういうイメージなのですが
実装イメージがわきません…

参考になるようなサイトやキーワードなどありましたらご助言いただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[このチュートリアル](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)がまさにそれだと思います。
Thymeleafというテンプレートエンジンを使って、テンプレートにJavaからパラメータを渡すことで、クエリストリングによって返すHTMLを変えるということを実現しています。

日本語だと[これ](http://dev.classmethod.jp/server-side/server/spring-html-webapp/)などでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！早速確認させていただきます！